# MySQL Case Sensitivity (or otherwise, how to store passwords correctly in MySQL)

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation, password-storage

**CAUSE:**

I have a table and the columns are all suitably `Collated` as `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pass_word` varchar(512) NOT NULL ,
  ...etc etc...
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_addr` (`email_addr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=989 ;
```

...Including the column storing the password hash (generated from `password_hash`) such as `$2y$14$tFpExwd2TXm43Bd20P4nkMbL1XKxwF.VCpL.FXeVRaUO3FFxGJ4Di`.

***BUT***, I find that due to the case insensitivity of the column, that a hash of `$2y$14$tFpExwd2tXm43Bd20P4NKmbL1XKxwF.VCpL.FxEVRaUO3FFxGJ4DI` would still allow access.

This means that there are potentially hundreds of collisions possible by storing the data in a case insensitive manner. Not good.

---

**ISSUE:**

Now, Is there a way of forcing MySQL to treat `pass_word` column as a **case sensitive** column, when doing comparisons. I want to avoid having to edit every occurance of the PHP/SQL querying, and instead simply set the database table column to compare in a case sensitive manner *by default*.

The `utf8mb4` character set does not give me any `_cs` options, and the only non-`_ci` option appears to be `utf8mb4_bin`.

So simple questions:

- <s>Does the `UTF8mb4_bin` character set & collation on MySQL treat standard comparisons case sensitively?</s>  [yes]
- Dose the `UTF8mb4_bin` suit what I want to do. Should I use another set, and if so, why?
- Are there any issues in storing `password_hash` outputs in a MySQL `utf8mb4_bin` column?
- Does this approach conveniently sidestep the need to edit the query SQL of each login query? Can I change the column type and then move on?

**EDIT**

> As detailed by nj_ , this is a silly issue that is not an issue at all because the value of `pass_word` is never directly edited when logging in.
>   ... It's been a long day.

Comment: I'm very confused by this "columns" business.  "I have a table full of columns." -- that is the definition of a table, what else do you mean by this?  "Including the column storing the password hash" -- could you clarify exactly what this is and why you are doing it?

Comment: I clarified my opening. The `pass_word` column is storing the hash data as a case-insensitive string @DigitalChris

Comment: It sounds like you're doing something equivalent to `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "<name>" AND password = "<password>"`, where `<password>` is the output of `password_hash()`. If that is the case, that's not going to work. You need to grab the `password` hash and call [password_verify()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: @nj_ no, that's not what I'm doing, my password setting and retrieval is fine, it's the storage I'm curious about. I know not to check hash against hash in that way, I do use `password_verify` :-D

Comment: I'm unsure as to what the concern is then. Because assuming you never perform a `SELECT` where you constrain by `password`, you shouldn't have any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really that worried about the potential 2^55 collisions in your 62^55 address space, you can simply change the column type to BLOB, which is always case-sensitive.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pass_word` BLOB NOT NULL ,
  ...etc etc...
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_addr` (`email_addr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=989 ;
```

Example:

`` INSERT INTO `users` (..., `pass_word`) VALUES (..., 'AbC'); ``

`` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pass_word` = 'AbC' LIMIT 0,1000; `` -> 1 hit

`` SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pass_word` = 'abc' LIMIT 0,1000; `` -> 0 hits

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered `Blob`. I assume that changing to blob column type would not require any update of the SQLs that checks password values?

Comment: I've made this change and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Or `VARBINARY(512)` ... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity is no problem in this case, because you cannot verify the password directly with SQL anyway. A correctly salted password hash cannot be searched for in the database. Search by username only and extract the stored hash from the database:

```
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
$db->prepare($sql);
$db->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
```

Afterwards you can extract the hash from the row and check the entered password against the found hash with the password_verify() function:

```
// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Comment: Yeah I realised this after comments from nj_ , I had a bit of blinkered vision on seeing that the storage is not case sensitive, regardless of the requirements. Thanks. I had added an edit to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Martin - Oh yes, i wasn't sure if it was really clear. Will probably delete the answer then.

Comment: No keep your answer, t's helpful. I should really delete the question but that works against me as it has answers.